# logging apache2 to mongodb: apache hook? something out there?

Tags: apache, logging, apache2, hook, mongodb

i just found a great blog posting on http://simonwillison.net/2009/Aug/26/logging/ stating the following

> MongoDB is fantastic for logging".
>   Sounds tempting... high performance
>   inserts, JSON structured records and
>   capped collections if you only want to
>   keep the past X entries. If you care
>   about older historic data but still
>   want to preserve space you could run
>   periodic jobs to roll up log entries
>   in to summarised records. It shouldn’t
>   be too hard to write a command-line
>   script that hooks in to Apache’s
>   logging directive and writes records
>   to MongoDB.

is there anything out there already? anyone already using apache logging with mongodb?

Comment: No way. I do not want my web server to block on IO trying to write something into a socket. There is nothing more stable than a file system -- if your file system failed you do not need to care about logging already.

So the whole idea of "Apache logging into MongoDB" seems very contrived to me. I would never take it seriously for more or less busy production site.

Comment: There is a appender for mongodb in combination with log4net: http://github.com/jsk/log4net-MongoDB

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to set Apache to write access logs to a perl script, which then does the needed work such as parsing, inserting into Mongo, and so on.

@Alexander, you don't need to have Apache block on IO.  Write your logger/perl script so it uses a message queue + threading.  Apache sends the log line to the perl script, which then inserts the message into a queue held in memory.  Another thread reads the queue and does the actual work.  We do this on our 1 billion+ views/month cache servers and it works without fail.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively recent option is to [use Flume to collect the logs](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2010/09/using-flume-to-collect-apache-2-web-server-logs/) and [use the MongoDB sink plugin for Flume](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/tree/master/flume_plugin) to write the events to MongoDB.